# is this solution of $\int_0^\infty \sin(z^2) dz $ valid?

Tags: complex-analysis, fake-proofs

Is this method valid?

We have $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}du = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$.

Let $u = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}x$, we get $\displaystyle \frac{1 + i}{\sqrt 2 }\int_0^{\infty }e^{-i x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi }{2 } \implies \int_0^\infty e^{-ix^2}dx = \frac{1-i}{2\sqrt 2 } \sqrt{\pi}$.

Comparing real and imaginary parts we get $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx = \int_0^{\infty}\cos(x^2)dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi }{2 \sqrt 2}$.

Comment: It's unclear where you use the substitution with $u$ since none of the integrals involve the variable $u$. But if $x$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, then $u$ is a line that goes from $0$ to infinity by a different route. Can you then just treat $u$ as if it were a real going from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: isn't $\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}du = \sqrt \pi /2$ for any complex variable $u$? I was asked to *discuss the validity of this solution*

Comment: Well, if you know that is true for any line from $0$ to $\infty$,  you'd be right, but it obviously can't be true for any such line, since if $u=ix$ for $x\geq 0$ real, $e^{-u^2}=e^{x^2}$, and thus the integral is not true.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so in general, $\int_0^\infty e^{-z^2}dz = \sqrt{\pi}/2$ is invalid. So this solution is invalid?

Comment: It would seem to be. $\int_{0}^\infty$ means along the real line, unless explicitly stated otherwise.  Why would you think it applies to a line in any other direction? If I remember correctly, the $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2}dz$ is constant when integrating along any line parallel to the real line - perhaps that is what you were thinking?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty$ part was confusing, if we were integrating along any other line, then we will have $\Large \int_0^\infty e^{-R^2 e^{i\theta}} e^{i 2 \theta }dR$. It appears that along the line $\theta = \frac \pi 4$ we have $\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}du = \frac{1}{2} (-1)^{1/8} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}$

Comment: Well, you'd need $2\theta$ since in the exponent, but yes, something like that. Maybe $$\int e^{-r^2e^{i2\theta}}e^{i\theta}dR$$

Comment: Woops ... edited!! thank you very much for discussion!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method works, but in present form it lacks justification. The key step is to prove that

> the integral of $\exp(-z^2)$ along the circular arc from $R$ to $Re^{\pi i/4}$ tends to $0$ as $R\to \infty$.

Once you have this, the Cauchy integral theorem tells you that 
$$\int_0^R \exp(-(re^{\pi i /4})^2)\,e^{\pi i/4}dr - \int_0^R \exp(-r^2)\,dr \to 0$$
as $  R\to\infty $. It follows that 
$$\int_0^\infty \exp(-r^2 i )\,dr =  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{-\pi i /4}$$
which is the desired result.

It remains to prove the statement emphasized above. First,
$$\left| \int_0^{\pi/4} \exp(-R^2 e^{2i\theta} )\,R\,d\theta \right| \le 
R\int_0^{\pi/4} \exp(-R^2 \cos 2\theta ) \,d\theta
\tag2$$ 
Next,  split the interval of integration into two subintervals at $\pi/4-R^{-3/2}$. The short interval contributes at most $R\cdot R^{-3/2}=R^{-1/2}$. On the long one the integrand is bounded by $\exp(-R^2 \cos (\pi/2-2R^{-3/2}) )$ where $$-R^2 \cos (\pi/2-2R^{-3/2})= - R^2 \sin (2R^{-3/2})\sim -2R^{1/2}$$ 
and of course $R\exp(-2R^{1/2})\to 0$ as $R\to \infty$.